# Setting focus to next page element on keypress

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, keypress

I'm having trouble setting the focus to the next element on the page from a data grid. The idea is that the user will navigate a data grid with arrow keys, but when pressing the `tab` key, the focus on the page will be moved from the data grid to an entirely different element within the page.

I'm trying to have the tab keypress set the focus to the next page element(outside of the data grid), but this doesn't seem to work with the current switch case I have setup:

```
document.querySelector('.ag-body').tabIndex=0;

let lastHeaderCell = false;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9 && e.shiftKey == true) {
    let currentFocusedElement = document.activeElement;
    let compId = currentFocusedElement.getAttribute("comp-id");
    currentFocusedElement.classList.add('focus-visible');
    console.log("Shift + Tab currently focused on: ", currentFocusedElement)
    let bodyFocused = document.querySelector('.ag-body').classList.contains('focus-visible');
    if(bodyFocused == true){
      document.querySelector('.ag-cell').classList.add('focus-visible');
    }
  }
  else if(e.key === "ArrowRight"){
    let headerId = document.activeElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("col-id");
    const headerCell = document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell:last-child').children[1].children[1];
    const hasFocusVisible = document.activeElement.classList.contains('focus-visible');
    if(lastHeaderCell === true) {
      document.querySelector('.ag-cell').focus();
      lastHeaderCell = false;
    }
    else if(headerCell.classList.contains('focus-visible')) {
      lastHeaderCell = true;
    }
  }
  else if(e.key === "ArrowDown"){
    //get column id on arrowdown
    let cellHeaderId = document.activeElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("col-id");
    document.querySelector('.ag-cell[col-id="' + cellHeaderId + '"]').focus();
  }
  else if(e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    //store value of grid cell column id
    let cellId = document.activeElement.getAttribute("col-id");
    let rowId = document.activeElement.parentElement.getAttribute("row-id");
    //set focus to column header if active cell is in first row and remove body cell focus
    if(rowId === "0"){
      document.querySelector('.ag-cell[col-id="' + cellId + '"]').classList.remove('ag-cell-focus');
      document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell[col-id="' + cellId + '"] .ag-header-cell-label').focus();
    }
  }
  else if(e.key === "Tab"){
    let header = document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell-label').classList.contains('focus-visible');
    console.log("Header has focus visible: ",header)
    //store currently focused cell on tab
    let currentFocusedElement = document.activeElement;
    let compId = currentFocusedElement.getAttribute("comp-id");
    console.log("Currently Focused Element: ",compId);
    //removes focus from current cell
    document.activeElement.blur();
    console.log("Active Element was: ", document.activeElement)
    if(header == true) {
      document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell').tabIndex = -1;
      document.querySelector('.ag-cell[col-id="' + compId + '"]').classList.add('ag-cell-focus');
    }
  }
});
```

**Example of current grid state: [Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/OMvXItvhcplevCtjEjC6?p=preview)**

Comment: You can use `document.activeElement.blur();` to set the focus to the body element. There seem to be other console errors in you linked example. They might be causing unintended side effects to.

Comment: @CaseyC - Thanks for the suggestion. I just realized I missed `activeElement` there! Part of the issue with setting the blur though, is that it doesn't push the focus out of the grid immediately. It seems to focus on the next cell, require another tab key press and THEN focus on the next element. I've updated my code and link to reflect the current state. Any ideas?

Comment: @CaseyC - Thoughts on why even though the focus is removed, it sets the next cell to focus and doesn't put it immediately on the next element outside of the grid?

Comment: Not exactly sure. I didn't realize you were trying to focus the `input` though. Your question made it sound like you wanted to focus the `body`. You can simply add an `id` to the input and use that to focus rather than `document.activeElement.blur()`. Or just get the input by tagName. That fixes the issue of having to tab twice to focus input. I'm not sure why but it doesn't seem to respect `e.preventDefault()` in your event handler so it always does the default operation for the tab key which is to move to the next cell.

Comment: @CaseyC - I've updated my question with more detail. I initially stated that the focus should be set to the body, but the intention is that the focus should move from the last focused element (using currentFocusedElement variable to store last focused element before tabbing) to the next element on the page, outside of the data grid. Storing the last active element is used for accessibility so that a user can then hit Shift + Tab to set focus back to the last element focused in the grid.

Comment: Got it. I'm just not entirely sure why it's not respecting `e.preventDefault()` onkeydown of the tab key. If you can figure that out your problem should be solved. Otherwise you can get the proper element through the event rather than through activeElement. Using `e.srcElement`. It still tabs forward no matter whether you stop propagation or prevent the default. My guess is it's something bound in the AgReact module you're using. Good luck, sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: @CaseyC - Thanks for continuing to help with this! I've updated my code in the question and the plnkr link to reflect a change I made which SHOULD set the focus on tab from the header to the first body cell with `document.querySelector('.ag-cell[col-id="' + compId + '"]').classList.add('ag-cell-focus');`, but is only setting the focus to `ag-body` because I set it with a tab index before the keydown event listener. Not sure how its not targeting the first cell, but getting the whole data body.

Comment: Just do `let currentFocusedElement = e.srcElement;
        let compId = currentFocusedElement.getAttribute("comp-id");
        let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        input.focus();`

Comment: @CaseyC - Sorry, I am trying to tackle a couple of issues with the data grid, and realized I've solved this issue. I'm trying to deal with the issue of `Shift` + `Tab` back into the data grid at the last focused cell, but its currently focusing on the whole data body and not the last focused cell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750918/setting-focus-on-previous-element-with-shift-tab?noredirect=1#comment90465216_51750918