# Setting focus on stored previous element with Shift + Tab

Tags: javascript, keypress, ag-grid

I am trying to set focus back to the previously focused page element using `Shift`+`Tab` keys to set the focus on the previously focused element within the data grid, whether that be a header cell or body cell. It is currently pushing the focus back to the header cells, I suspect because they have a tab index. I'm using the following that should be looking for the stored previously active element, and applying `focus-visible` class back to it:

```
document.querySelector('.ag-body').tabIndex=0;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9 && e.shiftKey == true) {
    let currentFocusedElement = event.srcElement;
    let compId = currentFocusedElement.getAttribute("comp-id");
    currentFocusedElement.classList.add('focus-visible');
    console.log("Shift + Tab currently focused on: ", currentFocusedElement)
    let bodyFocused = document.querySelector('.ag-body').classList.contains('focus-visible');
    console.log("Previously focused element", currentFocusedElement)
    if(bodyFocused == true){
      currentFocusedElement.classList.add('focus-visible');
    }
  }
  else if(e.key === "ArrowRight"){
    let headerId = document.activeElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("col-id");
    const headerCell = document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell:last-child').children[1].children[1];
    const hasFocusVisible = document.activeElement.classList.contains('focus-visible');
    if(lastHeaderCell === true) {
      document.querySelector('.ag-cell').focus();
      lastHeaderCell = false;
    }
    else if(headerCell.classList.contains('focus-visible')) {
      lastHeaderCell = true;
    }
  }
  else if(e.key === "ArrowDown"){
    //get column id on arrowdown
    let cellHeaderId = document.activeElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("col-id");
    document.querySelector('.ag-cell[col-id="' + cellHeaderId + '"]').focus();
  }
  else if(e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    //store value of grid cell column id
    let cellId = document.activeElement.getAttribute("col-id");
    let rowId = document.activeElement.parentElement.getAttribute("row-id");
    //set focus to column header if active cell is in first row and remove body cell focus
    if(rowId === "0"){
      document.querySelector('.ag-cell[col-id="' + cellId + '"]').classList.remove('ag-cell-focus');
      document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell[col-id="' + cellId + '"] .ag-header-cell-label').focus();
    }
  }
  else if(e.key === "Tab"){
    let header = document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell-label').classList.contains('focus-visible');
    console.log("Header has focus visible: ",header)
    //store currently focused cell on tab
    let currentFocusedElement = event.srcElement;
    let compId = currentFocusedElement.getAttribute("comp-id");
    console.log("Currently Stored Cell: ",compId);
    console.log("Currently Focused Element: ",currentFocusedElement)
    //removes focus from current cell
    document.activeElement.blur();
    console.log("Active Element was: ", document.activeElement)
    if(header == true) {
      document.querySelector('.ag-header-cell').tabIndex = -1;
      document.querySelector('.ag-cell[col-id="' + compId + '"]').classList.add('ag-cell-focus');
    }
  }
});
```

Link to current state: [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/OMvXItvhcplevCtjEjC6?p=preview)

Comment: and what excatly is your problem/error? or is it just that your code is not working?

Comment: How are you keeping track of the tab order if only some of the elements have a tabIndex?

Comment: @PhilippSander - The issue is that trying to tab back to the previously stored element automatically sets focus to the header, instead of the cell in the body of the data grid. Trying to figure out how to push back into the data grid body and set the focus back to the previously stored body cell.

Comment: @skyline3000 - each of the data grid body cells have a `comp-id` value that I'm storing when the user hits the tab key. This value is updated if the user hits the arrow key to the next cell, and then hits tab again.

Comment: @PhilippSander - I've tried adding a `tabindex = 0` to the `ag-body-container`, but can't get the previously focused cell to have focus again when the `ag-body-container` has class `focus-visible`. Any thoughts? I've updated my code above and the Plnkr link as well.

Comment: @Matt Are you positive `let currentFocusedElement = document.activeElement;` is always the correct element? I've seen cases when focusing elements without tabIndex, it actually makes the `document.body` the activeElement. Is there a reason you query the activeElement rather than just using the stored compId?

Comment: @skyline3000 - The way its setup, `let currentFocusedElement = document.activeElement;` will store the currently active element. `compId` is stored as a reference to a specific body cell, but is only used for body cells, not header cells. So, now I'm trying to find the stored cell if the ag-body-container has the focus. Hopefully that clears things up? Any thoughts?

Comment: @Matt is right. I f I add a `console.log(currentFocusedElement)` to your plunker when I hit the tab key it's the wrong element. That's why I suggested in your other post to use `event.srcElement` instead.

Comment: Also, you're checking for the shift+tab key press but you're never explicitly focusing the saved element in that check. Why are you assuming that it will focus automatically? Maybe I'm missing something? You should probably be using state to keep track of this.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/dumptruckman/accessible-react-table#readme

Comment: @CaseyC - I've updated the code in the question and plnkr with `event.srcElement`, which is getting the previously focused element now. However, I also have the `Shift` + `Tab` set to add the `focus-visible` class to the previously focused cell as well, but it continues to focus on the whole `ag-body` instead of the previously focused cell.

Comment: @CaseyC - Switching the tab index to `ag-cell` instead, allows the user to focus back into the cells, but it still won't allow me to set the cell that was stored when the user hit the `Tab` key. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a feeling that the overall feature you're trying to create might not be realistically achievable unless you're editing the [ag-grid source itself (the TypeScript files)](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/tree/master/packages/ag-grid/src/ts). You would need your own fork of ag-grid. I could be wrong, but bear this in mind.

Comment: @thirtydot - I was able to implement focus for the arrow key navigation with plain JS, so doing it for tab and shift+tab should be possible as well I would think.